# Xcode 7.1: UILabel added to sizeclass regular/regular shown anywhere

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.1

In Xcode 7, I was able to add a UILabel only to the Regular/Regular size-class. I simply selected **w: Regular h:Regular** below the storyboard and added it to my controller using drag 'n' drop. Once I switched to another size-class, the element was shown as inactive in the document outline on the left. Everything fine.

Now the same approach doesn't seem to work. When I switch to another size-class after the label was added to regular/regular, the UILabel is still active in the document outline and shown when the app is running (on an iPhone for example).

Any pointers or hints more than appreciated! Release notes don't offer any clue. Doesn't look like a wanted behaviour that was mentioned anywhere.

Comment: In the attributes inspector for the label make sure that it is only installed for the class size you want. I just checked under Xcode 7.1 and the behaviour is as you described for Xcode 7

Comment: Yeah, that works. I can uncheck the installed dialog and only add it to regular/regular. But this has to be done manually now, as it seems. (using Xcode 7.1.1)

Comment: That's the same version I tested with and as long as I selected the class size first, any,any was not installed by default. I.e. The behaviour is unchanged.